# preg_match PHP comments excluding if in quotes

Tags: php, comments, preg-match, quotes

I'm trying to write a regex to find and match commented text in PHP code files, everything I've this far works fine, but there's one exception:

my pattern:

```
$pattern='/((?:\/\*(?:[^*]|(?:\*+[^*\/]))*\*+\/)|(?:\/\/.*))/';
```

it still matches lines like this

```
$string="//this is not a comment"

$string2="/*this is not a comment */"
```

I know i need to add somewhere (?:^|[^"]+[^"]), but don't really know how, and is it even possible to avoid anything that is in between " "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex is going to be tricky, as you've already seen. But PHP has built in functions for parsing itself, like [token_get_all()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php).

Here's a simple test script that'll read the PHP code in a hypothetical file called `foo.php` and print out all the comments, regardless of the comment character (`//`, `#`, or `/* */`):

```
<?php
$code = file_get_contents('foo.php');
$tokens = token_get_all($code);
foreach ($tokens as $token) {
    if (is_array($token)) { // Sometimes the token element will be a single character, like ; . > ! etc.
        if (token_name($token[0]) === 'T_COMMENT' || token_name($token[0]) === 'T_DOC_COMMENT') {
            echo $token[1] . PHP_EOL;           
        }
    }
}
```